# Make TCP socket bi-directional in Thunderbird extension?

Tags: thunderbird-addon

In a Thunderbird extension I use the following code to wait for an incoming TCP connection:

```
function MyExtension_OnNewConnection(srvSock, newSock)
{
    var block = Components.interfaces.nsITransport.OPEN_BLOCKING |
        Components.interfaces.nsITransport.OPEN_UNBUFFERED;
    var istream = newSock.openInputStream(block, 0, 0);
    var ostream = newSock.openOutputStream(block, 0, 0);

    var cstream = Components.
        classes["@mozilla.org/scriptableinputstream;1"].
        createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIScriptableInputStream);
    cstream.init(istream);
    var y = cstream.read(1);
    cstream.close();
    if(y == "")
    {
        var y = "The socket is Tx-Only!\r\n";
        ostream.write(y, y.length);
    }

    istream.close();
    ostream.close();
}

...

waitSocket = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/server-socket;1"].
        createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIServerSocket);
waitSocket.init(-1, false, -1);
waitSocket.asyncListen({
    onSocketAccepted: MyExtension_OnNewConnection,
    onStopListening: function(socket, status) {}
});
```

According to the documentation `cstream.read()` can only return an empty string when the TCP socket is closed.

The `ostream.write()` function will send some data which is only possible if the TCP socket is not closed, yet.

However `cstream.read()` returns an empty string, `ostream.write()` sends some data and the other end of the TCP connection receives the string!

This means that the TCP connection is **monodirectional** (from the beginning!).

Questions:

- Why?
- How can I make the TCP conenction bidirectional so I can receive data?

What I already tried:

- not to use `OPEN_BLOCKING` nor `OPEN_UNBUFFERED` flags => No effect.
- checking `istream.available()` in a loop instead of using `cstream` => Will always return 0 even if data has been sent by the other end of the TCP connection.

Answer (score 0):

I analyzed the source code of Thunderbird:

Obviously `openInputStream` uses a quite "simple" implementation if `OPEN_UNBUFFERED` is set and `OPEN_BLOCKING` is not set while a rather complex implementation is used for the three other combinations.

The simple implementation works perfectly however blocking socket access is not possible then.

Another page says that Javascript functions should be written in a non-blocking way so I decided to use the following implementation:

```
function CalledOnTimer()
{
    try
    {
        while(true)
        {
            data = cstream.read(NumberOfBytes);
            if(data == "")
            {
                /* Socket has been closed */
                cstream.close();
                istream.close();
                ostream.close();
                ...
                return;
            }
            /* Process the data */
            ...
        }
    }
    catch(dummy)
    {
        /* Currently no (more) data on the socket */
        restartTheTimer();
    }
}

...
var istream = newSock.openInputStream(
    Components.interfaces.nsITransport.OPEN_UNBUFFERED, 0, 0);
...
cstream.init(istream);
...
startTheTimer();
```